# Backslash in JSON on request body for ExpressJS- with body-parser

Tags: node.js, json, express, body-parser

Everything looks like OK unless a backslash char in JSON comes from client to the Express server with body-parser.

Request body is like this (We put this onto Postman (raw value) and Swagger-UI as is:

```
{
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "abc%\-xyz"
}
```

Postman's curl code is like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:3000/login \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: ef96edfd-dc43-47fe-89c0-76e562fa206d' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "abc%\-xyz"
}'
```

Swagger-UI's curl code:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:3000/login" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"username\": \"admin\", \"password\": \"abc%\\-xyz\"}"
```

I . don't know what's the difference between Swagger-UI and Postman but it looks like there is one more backslash in Swagger's curl. But there is no difference on the server side.

Indeed, I cannot control the request body which comes from the client and the passwords can have such characters like backslash. App always gives this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 45
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (/path/to/project/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:93:19)
    at /path/to/project/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/path/to/project/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/path/to/project/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/path/to/project/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1103:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

If JSON becomes with two backslashes (\):

```
{
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "abc%\\-xyz"
}
```

Then there is no error anymore on the server side (inside of the route.post() function) but the body.password has still two backslashes: `abc%\\-xyz`

As it was stated on the comments, it may be a problem of parsing.

What is the correct way to deal with this?
`bodyParser.json({strict: false})` doesn't help

Comment: You say "JSON" but you don't show any JSON string. Your question seems to be related to parsing that string. If you have a question about the JSON (string), why not show it to us? Why show us the original and/or already parsed object but not the actual JSON (string!) data that your question is about?

Comment: @Mörre The first block of code is a valid JSON string.

Comment: @Mörre this is what we put in Postman and also Swagger-UI. If there is no backslash in the password value, it works as expected. So I don't think that I misguided you. Sorry if I misunderstand your statement.

Comment: @Mörre Thank you for the comment, I have checked the curl codes for both Postman and Swagger-UI and I added them to the question. But there is no difference on the serverside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just trying to fix broken clients.

The fact that your server already accepts passwords with a backslash shows this.

If you turn on strict mode for your Jason parser, everything becomes moredictable, as the parser no longer tries to make educated guesses on how it thinks your data should look. This also means that you now have to send JSON from your postman client, instead of your self-invented protocol, so send `"test\\"` when your password is `\`.

This is because a slash (and a double quote) have special meaning when used in a JSON string, and thus they get special treatment, somethings that other characters don't get. The same goes for when someones password contains a `"`, if this is the case, a client must send `\"` to your server.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understand this. But one backslash disappears on the server which you say the JSON is not valid (ok), but with two backslashes: `abc%\\-xyz` this becomes still with two backslashes on the server. How should I deal with this?

Comment: How are you printing the string? If you use console.log with an object, it Automatically doubles the slash for display purposes, so you can quickly copy your object from your console. Try printing out the password, or writing it to a file, so you are sure no display formatters are changing it

Comment: Thank you, as you have stated, console.log() with two params as object makes things confusing. Only string param shows the correct value. And so I understand that the app problem is also another subject not related to parsing.